# Shopify: Display units sold of a product on website and progress bar

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I want to display the units sold of a product on my website as well as a progress bar.  Here is the current code Im working with but the number stays at 0 and the progress bar is empty.  Any tips on what I could be doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help!

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Product Progress Bar",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "product",
      "id": "product_id",
      "label": "Product"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "bar_color",
      "label": "Progress Bar Color",
      "default": "#FF0000"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "border_color",
      "label": "Progress Bar Border Color",
      "default": "#000000"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}

{% assign product = all_products[settings.product_id] %}
{% assign orders = product.orders %}
{% assign totalUnits = 0 %}
{% for order in orders %}
  {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
    {% if line_item.product_id == product.id %}
      {% assign totalUnits = totalUnits | plus: line_item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign unitsSold = totalUnits %}
{% assign progress = unitsSold | divided_by: product.total_inventory %}

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-text">Units Sold: {{unitsSold}}</div>
  <div class="progress-bar" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 20px;">
    <div class="progress" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: {{progress}}%; height: 100%; background-color: {{settings.bar_color}};"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar-border" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid {{settings.border_color}};"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.progress-bar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-bar-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}

.progress {
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.progress-bar-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid {{settings.border_color}};
}
</style>
```

Im not sure if the names of my variable to get the data from Shopify such as the units sold is correct. I think that's where my problem is or how I'm trying to display it, not sure.